# marking end of words in luatex - problem with math

Tags: math-mode, luatex, callback

I'm trying to mark the end of "words" (including punctuation) with luatex callbacks. (At the end I want to inject space chars at this positions, but the example uses rules for the visualization).

With some code based on `\countwords` from the `chickenize` package it works quite fine. I only have a problem with math: I would like to avoid to get marks there.  Trying to do it with an attribute set in `\everymath` doesn't work as can be seen in the code below: It also affects other places like e.g. tabulars where math mode is used internally.

Has someone an idea how to exclude only "real" math from the mark function?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,amsmath}

\newattribute\mathattr

\begin{luacode}

local MATHATTR         = luatexbase.registernumber ("mathattr")
local nodetraverseid   = node.traverse_id
local nodegetattribute = node.get_attribute
local GLUE             = node.id("glue")
local GLYPH            = node.id("glyph")

local function insertmark (head,current)
 local pdfstring = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
       pdfstring.data =
       string.format("q 1 0 0 RG 1 0 0 rg 0.4 w 0 %g m 0 %g l S Q",-3,10)
       head = node.insert_after(head,current,pdfstring)
 return head
end

local markwords = function(head)
  for glyph in nodetraverseid(GLYPH,head) do
   if glyph.next and (glyph.next.id == GLUE) 
      and not nodegetattribute(glyph,MATHATTR)
   then
      insertmark(head,glyph)
   end
  end
  return head
end


luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",markwords,"markwords")

luatexbase.add_to_callback("hpack_filter",markwords,"markwords")

\end{luacode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{l}
xxx xxx
\end{tabular}

$a=b \int f(x) =0\quad  \text{abc abc abc abc} $

\everymath{\setattribute\mathattr{1}}

\begin{tabular}{l}
xxx xxx
\end{tabular}

$a=b \int f(x) =0\quad \text{abc abc abc abc} $

\bigskip

VA VA 
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The math content is enclosed by `math` nodes, with subtype 0 marking beginning, and subtype 1 marking closing of the math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,amsmath}

\newattribute\mathattr

\begin{luacode}

local MATHATTR         = luatexbase.registernumber ("mathattr")
local nodetraverseid   = node.traverse_id
local nodetraverse     = node.traverse
local nodegetattribute = node.get_attribute
local GLUE             = node.id("glue")
local GLYPH            = node.id("glyph")
local MATH             = node.id("math")
local HLIST            = node.id("hlist")
local VLIST            = node.id("vlist")


local function insertmark (head,current)
 local pdfstring = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
       pdfstring.data =
       string.format("q 1 0 0 RG 1 0 0 rg 0.4 w 0 %g m 0 %g l S Q",-3,10)
       head = node.insert_after(head,current,pdfstring)
 return head
end

local function markwords(head)
  local inside_math = false
  for n in nodetraverse(head) do
    local id = n.id
    if id == GLYPH then
      local glyph = n
      if glyph.next and (glyph.next.id == GLUE) 
        and not (inside_math or nodegetattribute(glyph,MATHATTR))
      then
        insertmark(head,glyph)
      end
    elseif id == MATH then
      inside_math = (n.subtype == 0)
    end
  end
  return head
end


luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",markwords,"markwords")

luatexbase.add_to_callback("hpack_filter",markwords,"markwords")

\end{luacode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{l}
xxx xxx
\end{tabular}

$a=b \int f(x) =0\quad  \text{abc abc abc abc} $


\everymath{\setattribute\mathattr{1}}

\begin{tabular}{l}
xxx xxx
\end{tabular}

$a=b \int f(x) =0\quad \text{abc abc abc abc} $

\bigskip

VA VA 
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Contrary to your screenshot, the code in your question doesn't put bar behind last word in `\text{abc abc abc abc}` and at the end of a paragraph:

[image]

Comment: `elseif id == MATH then
   inside_math =(n.subtype == 0)
 end`  is a bit shorter

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do exactly what I want. And I don't have a bar after the last abc in \text too, but you can't see it, as my screenshot has been clipped and shows only the first tree words.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah, it is good to know that it is not an issue

Comment: I also removed the attribute from the test, it is not needed with your code, and I added a test for the glyph width, to avoid that 0-space gets marked: `glyph.next and (glyph.next.id == GLUE)
        and not inside_math and (glyph.next.width >0)`.